# Issues with files using Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

My code is conceptually something like this

```
import multiprocessing.dummy

def working_with_files(test_file):
    open test_file
    ...bunch of stuff...
    create_fileA(variable)
    create_fileB_from_fileA(fileA)
    os.remove(fileA)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = glob("/Users/Name/Documents/TestData/*")
    pool = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(8)
    results = pool.map(working_with_files, files)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

From my understanding, each thread is running concurrently, but inside each thread, its still happening in sequence. Since each thread is a function, everything inside the function should still be happening in sequence. I am, however, getting some weird errors. For example, when trying to os.remove(fileA), it says fileA doesn't exist (only occurs sometimes); however, it should exist since I'm only running that line after creating the file. These errors don't exist for single threads.

Comment: Incomplete pseudocode isn’t much use to help diagnose a problem like this, where the details matter. Please edit your code to be a [mre] so anyone can paste it into a file and _without adding anything_ run it to see the same problem as you see with that code.

Comment: Is it possible that different threads could create files with the same file name?

Comment: barny, Thanks. Sorry for the lacking code. I will work on a better example. @YouweiLiang Thanks, that was one of the issues in the dataset. Another issue I think is that in the beginning of the process I create a file. Same name each time so it's getting overwritten. Theoretically should still work since the file is never deleted and always exists. Even though I'm not deleting that file, it seems to be causing an issue. I think it's because in the process of overwriting, it might be locking the file up making it inaccessible for a moment for the next thread?

Comment: @AskioFrio I try to answer the question below.

Answer (score 0):

In the comment section, @AskioFrio confirmed that different threads could create files with same filenames. So I think the issue is [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) which could be illustrated with the following example (steps happening sequentially):

1. Thread A creates a file `abc`.
2. Thread B creates a file with the same filename `abc`; so `abc` gets overwritten.
3. Thread A deletes `abc`.
4. Thread B tries to delete `abc`, which has been deleted by thread A and thus the error occurs.

Actully the most notable race conditions happen in system memory when multiple threads try to write to the memory on the same address (e.g., writing to the same element in an array).

To avoid the race conditions, you may use lock or semaphore to coordinate the activities of threads.